# Display Apache Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

Is there any way to display the effective configuration values that Apache is using?

I have a cPanel server that uses multiple include files and there are some server-wide settings that are defined in multiple places.  I'd like to find a way of confirming which value Apache is actually using while it's running.

Comment: related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943
https://superuser.com/questions/922869
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129026
https://serverfault.com/questions/425894
https://serverfault.com/questions/696164
https://serverfault.com/questions/500329
https://serverfault.com/questions/489018
https://serverfault.com/questions/42539

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/invoking.html

Answer (score 25, accepted):

mod_info provides what you need, I think.

```
<Location /server-info>
   SetHandler server-info
   Order deny,allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 1.2.3.4 # your IP, subnet, whatever
</Location>
```

More here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html

You can also list the configuration of your VirtualHosts (less info than using the above) using the command `sudo httpd -S`.

Comment: Lucky me, mod_info was already compiled in too.

Comment: +1 It works like a charm! For the beginners like me, I would also remember to load the `mod_info` module in `httpd.conf` by adding the line: `LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so`