# Web based Apache VHost config dump

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there a native way to get a simple HTML / XML & XSD output for Apache VHost and Directives?

On console I write:

```
apachectl -S
```

If there is no native one, is there an (open) Script / Tool (php, perl, etc.) managing this.

I'm NOT looking for server management but just for a "server config overview" which might be (iframe) included in a wiki page for references on different development machines.

Comment: related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943
https://superuser.com/questions/922869
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129026
https://serverfault.com/questions/425894
https://serverfault.com/questions/696164
https://serverfault.com/questions/500329
https://serverfault.com/questions/489018
https://serverfault.com/questions/42539

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/invoking.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably want [**mod_info**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html)

NOTE that apache configuration is not XML.

Comment: yeah, but it's not really user-friendly / readable for documentation purposes?!

Comment: What's wrong with the configuration ? That's as readable as it is going to get, since anything you derive from that will be...derived from that.

Comment: At the moment http://www.askapache.com/pub/servers/mod_info.c.html provides sourcecode for mod_info /server-info .

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for httpd:

`-S     Show the settings as parsed from the config file (currently only shows the virtualhost settings).`

Comment: Yes, that's what I read on console and want to get in HTML format for documentation purposes automatically?! Didn't get it why this should be an answer?!

Comment: If you'd mentioned in your question that you had already tried that option, I wouldn't have given that answer. Last I checked, it was possible to include raw text into a web page.

Comment: Dear @Jenny, I DID wrote it above: "On console I write …" nevertheless, that's not what I'm looking for and thank you

Comment: apachectl != httpd... but never mind.

Comment: right, but does exactly the same here and also gives exactly the same output with -h for me (self-compiled Apache 2.4 without distr. changes)

Comment: Note that `apachectl -S` shows the configuration as it is parse from the filesystem, which is not necessarily the config that is loaded into apache.

Comment: @immeëmosol Right, it says that right there in the quoted man page.