# Is there a method of viewing/exporting the current running config of Apache as a single file?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, configuration-management

I'm running Apache2 on Ubuntu and the configuration is spread over several files.
Is there a command to export all configuration data in use to a single file?

I would like to compare it to another servers configuration in a side by side manner.

Comment: related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943
https://superuser.com/questions/922869
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129026
https://serverfault.com/questions/425894
https://serverfault.com/questions/696164
https://serverfault.com/questions/500329
https://serverfault.com/questions/489018
https://serverfault.com/questions/42539

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/invoking.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Enable [mod_info](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_info.html), browse to your server at http://your.host.example.com/server-info , and save the file.

> **Apache Module mod_info**
>
> Description:  Provides a comprehensive overview of the server
>   configuration

This can be very handy to compare the running configuration for two or more Apache nodes in a webserver cluster.

Comment: How could I get that mod? I'm running Ubuntu. Is there a package for it?

Comment: Nvm mind, found it.