# Can I view the resolved config Apache is using?

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, httpd.conf

Is there a way to view the final "effective" config a running Apache instance is using after resolving any/all includes and the like?

I'm looking at a config that has a web of includes and suspect some of the issues I'm having are related to the order in which everything falls into place. I think it's apachectl that can validate a config has no syntax errors, but I'm wondering if I can go a step further and somehow output the fully assembled config. Any advice (short of cleaning up this mess of includes that should never have been allowed to happen)?

Comment: related :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152943
https://superuser.com/questions/922869
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129026
https://serverfault.com/questions/425894
https://serverfault.com/questions/696164
https://serverfault.com/questions/500329
https://serverfault.com/questions/489018
https://serverfault.com/questions/42539

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_info.html
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/invoking.html

Answer (score 6):

Yes, to a certain degree, but I think it covers your requirement.
You can use [`mod_info`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_info.html) for this.

From the online documentation (emphasis mine):

> #### Dumping the configuration on startup
>
> If the `config` define `-DDUMP_CONFIG` is set, `mod_info` will dump the pre-parsed configuration to stdout during server startup. Pre-parsed means that directives like `<IfDefine>` and `<IfModule>` are evaluated and environment variables are replaced. However it does not represent the final state of the configuration. In particular, **it does not represent the merging or overriding that may happen for repeated directives**.
>
> This is roughly equivalent to the `?config` query.

and:

> [...]views of the configuration information are available by appending a query to the `server-info` request. For example, `http://your.host.example.com/server-info?config` will show all configuration directives.
>
> **?config**
>
> Just the configuration directives, not sorted by module

As an example, for a default configuration in Fedora 22, the lines marked as `In file` are included from the main `httpd.conf` file:

```
# curl -v http://localhost/server-info?config | elinks -dump
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /server-info?config HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: localhost
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 02 Jun 2015 20:49:43 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Fedora)
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
<
{ [8014 bytes data]
100  8561    0  8561    0     0  1792k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 2090k
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
                       Apache Server Information

   Configuration:
       In file: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
         42: Listen 80
         66: User apache
         67: Group apache
         86: ServerAdmin root@localhost
        102: <Directory />
        103:   AllowOverride none
        104:   Require all denied
           : </Directory>
        119: DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
        124: <Directory "/var/www">
        125:   AllowOverride None
        127:   Require all granted
           : </Directory>
        131: <Directory "/var/www/html">
        144:   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        151:   AllowOverride None
        156:   Require all granted
           : </Directory>
        164: DirectoryIndex index.html
        171: <Files ".ht*">
        172:   Require all denied
           : </Files>
        182: ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
        189: LogLevel warn
        196: LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\"
       \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
        197: LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
        201: LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\"
       \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
        217: CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
        247: ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
        255: <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
        256:   AllowOverride None
        257:   Options None
        258:   Require all granted
           : </Directory>
        266: TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
        283: AddType application/x-compress .Z
        284: AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
        305: AddType text/html .shtml
        306: AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
        316: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
        324: MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
        348: EnableSendfile on
       In file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf
         16: IndexOptions FancyIndexing HTMLTable VersionSort
         21: Alias /icons/ "/usr/share/httpd/icons/"
         23: <Directory "/usr/share/httpd/icons">
         24:   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
         25:   AllowOverride None
         26:   Require all granted
           : </Directory>
         34: AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress
       x-gzip
         36: AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
         37: AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
         38: AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
         39: AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
         41: AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
         42: AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
         43: AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
         44: AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
         45: AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
         46: AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
         47: AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
         48: AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
         49: AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
         50: AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
         51: AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
         52: AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
         53: AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
         54: AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
         55: AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
         56: AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core.
         58: AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
         59: AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
         60: AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
         61: AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
         67: DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
         85: ReadmeName README.html
         86: HeaderName HEADER.html
         92: IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
       In file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_dnssd.conf
          2: DNSSDEnable on
       In file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf
         17: UserDir disabled
         31: <Directory "/home/*/public_html">
         32:   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit Indexes
         33:   Options MultiViews Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
       IncludesNoExec
         34:   Require method GET POST OPTIONS
           : </Directory>
       In file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
          8: <LocationMatch "^/+$">
          9:   Options -Indexes
         10:   ErrorDocument 403 /.noindex.html
           : </LocationMatch>
         13: <Directory /usr/share/httpd/noindex>
         14:   AllowOverride None
         15:   Require all granted
           : </Directory>
         18: Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
       In file: /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
        355: <Location "/server-info">
        356:   SetHandler server-info
           : </Location>
```